# Using Hashtables/Dictionaries with string keys & Case Insensitive Searching

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, dictionary, hashtable, case-insensitive

Wondering if this is possible.

We have an 3rd Party library that contains identification information about users...

The main interaction with the library is through a HashTable which is keyed with a string, and returns an Object Graph of information for that key.

The problem is, the key is obviously Case Sensitive, but what we get from the users browser doesn't necessarily match the case... (We often get the key fully lowercase'd)

I'm wondering if it's possible to do a case Insensitive key search against a hashtable.

e.g.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.Add("MyKey", "Details");

string result = ht["MyKey"];
string result = ht["MYKEY"];
string result = ht["mykey"];
```

On the off chance we could submit a support ticket to the company to add this functionality, are there any other DataStructures (i.e. the new generic collections/dictionaries) that support this functionality

Lastly, would it be possible to override the System.String GetHashCode() method, to 
make all case invariant strings return the same hashcode... e.g. I'm thinking this is a no goer as `string` is a sealed class

Cheers if anyone has any suggestions

Comment: as an aside: if you are using .NET 3.5 you should probably stop using Hashtable etc - and start using the generic collections instead.

Comment: Re your comment: maybe just call .ToLowerInvariant() on all your keys, then.

Comment: *scratches head* But the keys that are inside the Hashtable aren't ToLowered(). I.e. I'm given a pre-built hashtable that's instantiated/populated inside a dll. and the keys in HT are Case-Sensitive... The only access I have to the dll is via an getter/indexer where I pass the key, so even if I toLowerInvarianted my keys on the outside, they wouldn't match the keys on the inside.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Code to make the hashtable comparisons case-insensitive

For 2.0, 3.0, 3.5

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

You can get info on InvariantCultureIgnoreCase vs. OrdinalIgnoreCase on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188241/which-version-of-stringcomparer-to-use) SO link

OR

```
Hashtable ht = System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionsUtil.CreateCaseInsensitiveHashtable();
```

Because case-insensitive dictionary collection is such a common use, the .NET Framework has a CollectionUtil class that supports creating Hashtable and SortedList objects that are case insensitive. Use by calling CreateCaseInsensitiveHashtable or CreateCaseInsensitiveSortedList.

For .Net 1.0 (I am not sure if 1.0 supports StringComparer)

```
public class InsensitiveComparer : IEqualityComparer
{
    CaseInsensitiveComparer _comparer = new CaseInsensitiveComparer();
    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString().ToLowerInvariant().GetHashCode();
    }

    public new bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        if (_comparer.Compare(x, y) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
       {
           return false;
       }
    }
}

Hashtable dehash = new Hashtable(new InsensitiveComparer());
```

Comment: The StringComparer class already provides case-insensitive comparers - no need to implement your own.

Comment: This is just an FYI: I found out that StringDictionary keys are case insensitive by default. But both the key and value must be strings.

Comment: Also you can use CreateCaseInsensitiveHashtable. Edited my response to reflect the usage.

Answer (score 17):

With a dictionary:

```
new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

but simpler, I believe `StringDictionary` is case-insensitive too:

```
    StringDictionary ht = new StringDictionary();
    ht.Add("MyKey", "Details");

    string result1 = ht["MyKey"];
    string result2 = ht["MYKEY"];
    string result3 = ht["mykey"];
```

Comment: Cheers Marc. And cheers to the others for pointing out the IEqualityOperator overloads... Unfortunately, I've no access to the internals of the library or the construction of the Hashtable... I only discovered the implementation by using Reflector to poke 
around inside it. I think I'll log a support ticket with the company and ask them if it can be added as a "Feature"

Answer (score 2):

You can supply an case-insensitive `IEqualityComparer` to the `HashTable` constructor, but this requires that you can influence the `HashTable` construction in the 3rd party library.

If you fill the hash table from your code, you could normalize the keys on insertion and retrieve normalized keys again.

If you are unable to influence the content of the hash table, but you know the structure of the keys, you could correct the user input before accessing the hash table.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very efficient way, but you could always take the hashtable and make a StringDictionary from it:

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.Add("FOO", "bar");

StringDictionary dict = new StringDictionary();

foreach(string key in ht.Keys)
    dict.Add(key, ht[key].ToString());

string result = dict["foo"]; // Assigns "bar" to result
```

Comment: +1 This is nice idea. (But fails on "FOO" and "foo" in the hash table.)

Comment: Well, using the indexer instead of the Add method would prevent an exception, and wouldn't any solution have the same problem, if the original Hashtable has multiple keys that differ by case only?