# Why can't I define a case-insensitve Dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, case-insensitive

This C#/WPF code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestDict28342343
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Dictionary<string, string> variableNamesAndValues = 
                new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        }
    }
}
```

gives me the **error**:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Dictionary(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Yet I find this code example **everywhere** such as **[here](https://svn.mindtouch.com/source/public/dekiwiki/trunk/src/tools/mindtouch.deki.twconverter/TWConverter.cs)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188241/which-version-of-stringcomparer-to-use)**.

**How can I define a Dictionary whose keys are case-insensitve?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're trying to using [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx), which is an enum. You should be using [`StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.invariantcultureignorecase.aspx) instead - that's a property returning a [`StringComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx), which implements [`IEqualityComparer<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx). You'll then end up calling the [`Dictionary<,>` constructor overload accepting an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072(v=VS.90).aspx) which it can use to check for equality and generate hash codes.

Answer (score 3):

Pass StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.  Note StringCompar**er** not StringCompar**ison**.

More generally, the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` constructor can take an argument of type `IComparer<TKey>`.  As Jon notes, StringComparison is an enum.  But StringComparer provides some "canned" implementation of `IComparer<string>`, and it's the latter that you need.

Answer (score 1):

This works on my computer:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>( StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase ).
```