# Case Insensitive Dictionary not working

Tags: vb.net, generics, dictionary, case-insensitive

I have spend a couple of hours trying to figure out why my generic Dictionary(Of String, String) is not ignoring case.

Here is my code:

```
Dim test As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)(System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
test.Add("FROG", "1")
Console.WriteLine(test.ContainsKey("frog"))
```

The console shows  "False"  every time.  It should be showing "True".

If I use:

```
Console.WriteLine(test."frog"))
```

I get a KeyNotFoundException.

It seems as if the Comparer parameter is being completely ignored.

What is going on?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491403/why-cant-i-define-a-case-insensitve-dictionary-in-c), it's a simple spelling mistake.

The issue is System.**StringComparison**.OrdinalIgnoreCase is an Integer Enum.
It should be System.**StringComparer**.OrdinalIgnoreCase

*New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)(System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)* is actually calling the **New(capacity As Integer)** overloaded constructor, and passing 5.

So, to make it all work as expected, the instantiation line should read:

```
Dim test As New System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)(System.StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Comment: Wow good eye and now I remember why I can't stand implicit conversion.